# PDI "Google Spreadsheet Input/Output" plugin compatible with Google Sheets API v4?

Tags: java, compatibility, google-sheets-api, pentaho-data-integration

I am using the "Google Spreadsheet Input/Output" plugin from the Pentaho Data Integration marketplace, which is no longer maintained. [Github repository link](https://github.com/GlobalTechnology/pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin). Recently I have received an email from Google with the subject:

> [Action Required] Google Sheets v3 API is being shutdown on March 3, 2020

Can someone please have a look the source code and check if the plugin is using API v3 or v4. Not being a Java developer, I tried to find out myself, but looking at the code I don't have a clue.

I also posted this [question](https://community.hitachivantara.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/view-question?ContributedContentKey=dc0c47f4-bf1d-45e6-aa74-441b4549901b&CommunityKey=e0eaa1d8-5ecc-4721-a6a7-75d4e890ee0d) to the Hitachi Pentaho community forum. But instead of answering the question, they removed the plugin from the marketplace without any further comment.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that this plugin is the latest one (I am the author) : https://github.com/jfmonteil/Pentaho-Google-Sheet-Plugin
It uses Google Drive API V3 for parsing and Google Sheets API V4. I have just upgraded the code to be up to date with the deprecated components.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I'm sure this will be of good value to whoever comes to the party now. For us, not being Java devs, we had to migrate the Google Sheets processing to Python 2 years ago. I will make this the accepted answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Since Google Sheets v4 API [was announced](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/apps-dev-sheets-api?utm_campaign=drive_launch_google_sheets_api_061416&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc) in 2016 and the last edit to the code was in 2014, there is no doubt this plugin was done with the v3 API version.

Also, the Readme file links to "https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/", which redirects to "https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/", the old documentation of V3.

Comment: True. @toms posted a Github clone, which is supposed to work with V4. Source code points to [V4 resources](https://github.com/huantaoliu/pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin/blob/be9625d951343ca35a7a50a57dfd8f1662acca12/src/main/java/org/ccci/gto/pdi/trans/steps/googlespreadsheet/spreadsheet/SheetsQuickstart.java#L15).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can use the CData JDBC driver. It is very easy to use and integrate. 
https://www.cdata.com/drivers/gsheets/jdbc/
Disadvantage: It's not free.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I'll give the clone you found a try first.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a Github clone that has been updated to work with v4. But couldn't try it out yet.

https://github.com/huantaoliu/pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin

Comment: This looks promising, will try asap (end of January) and post results here.

Comment: @stack_lech: if you are able to build the plugin could you make it available? Thanks.

Comment: All of the 27 forks seem to be not working, because they have outdated pom.xml files. The good news is, that after investing a whole day I managed to create a working pom.xml and I could build the plugin successfully. I will do some tests, roll it out and fork another working version then. Will share new repo here and ready built plugin with you, if you don't want to build yourself. Stay tuned.

Comment: You can use this link to get the pre-compiled package which is working with API v4. I'm using the gsheet input step in a production system for a week now. I didn't test output step though, which I know was not working properly in the original plugin. I haven't created a new fork yet. But I will asap. Link: https://mega.nz/#!cclHBCSR

Comment: I'm prompted to enter a decryption key to download the file.

Comment: Please try this [https://mega.nz/#!5INGWSxJ!djSXbv3eSWXZbXZgnaG35BNvW_d7bHb7QKvkS7EY-to]. I could see a few deprecated warnings while building the project. We are investigating this. As of now, I cannot guarantee that this will work after 3rd of March 2020. Will keep you updated.

Comment: By updating the dependencies in the pom.xml the plugin is using API v4, so we're good.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version that is compatible with v4 and comes with some additional features like appending rows.

https://github.com/jfmonteil/Pentaho-Google-Sheet-Plugin